# Is there a quantum algorithm to find SHA256 collisions?

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, cryptography

As I understand, the Bitcoin network can be seen as a supercomputer looking for SHA256 collisions. It hasn't found one yet (March 2022). Also, in the post-quantum cryptography era, you would be capable of reversing SHA256 hashes.

But in the case of finding hash collisions, is there an algorithm already proposed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [BHT algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9705002) finds collisions in a hash with $N$ outputs in around $\sqrt[3]{N}$ evaluations, i.e., around $2^{85}$ for SHA-256. Realistically, that's too slow to be practical.

In principle, it might be possible to do better by exploiting special properties of SHA-256. [This paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/213) has some quantum attacks on reduced-round versions of some hash functions that are better than the best known classical attacks, but reduced-round attacks don't work on the full-round hashes used in the real world.

> in the post-quantum cryptography era, you would be capable of reversing SHA256 hashes.

SHA-256 can't be reversed because it's many-to-one. If you rephrase the problem as finding any string with the same hash—not necessarily the one that was originally hashed—then you can use Grover's algorithm, but it takes around $\sqrt{N}=2^{128}$ hash evaluations.

I think some people imagine that because quantum circuits are reversible, you can run them backwards to invert any function. If you had a circuit that turned $x$ into $\text{SHA-256}(x)$ then you could do that, but no one knows how to make that circuit. They know how to make a circuit that turns $(x,y)$ into $(x,y\oplus \text{SHA-256}(x))$, but that circuit is its own inverse, so running it backwards doesn't help to invert SHA-256.

Comment: This is right, except the comment about "SHA-256 can't be reversed because it's many-to-one" is maybe a little awkward.  If you had a quantum algorithm that could efficiently create a uniform superposition over all $x$ such that the $\text{SHA-256}$ hash of $x$ were equal to the given $y$ then you would have effectively reversed the hash and can find collisions by repeatedly running your efficient algorithm.

Comment: I'd also add that there are some concerns regarding the BHT algorithm, since it requires an exponential number of qubits. Bernstein explains in this article (https://cr.yp.to/hash/collisioncost-20090517.pdf) that using a classical computer which scales exponentially with the size of the problem, we can parallelize our search and reach similar performances to the BHT algorithm.

Comment: Also, the article you link exploits differential paths with a probability slightly lower than the Birthday bound, so that they can achieve a better complexity than $\sqrt{2^n}$ using Grover's. However, these attack remains exponential in the size of the problem.